# AWS Load Balancers taking twenty minutes or more to recognise a newly added instance is healthy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

At my current place of work we have a number of services that are running on Elastic Beanstalk. Deploying new versions to these Elastic Beanstalk services can sometimes take the best part of an hour.

Looking at the Elastic Beanstalk events page you can see it takes almost 25 minutes for a new instance to be detected as healthy and added.

[image: ElasticBeanstalkEventsOutput]

When I check the instances in the EC2 console and also via the Auto Scaling Group they appear to be healthy. When I check to see what the load balancer is doing it shows the new instance as being out of service. From observation it appears to be the load balancer's tardiness in recognising the new instances as being healthy that is responsible for the delay. [image: LoadBalancerView].

Does anyone know why this could be?

I appreciate this is a rather open question and the short answer is to upgrade these services to use ECS but as that isn't going to happen in the next few months it would be nice to at least know why it's taking so long.

These are the Health Check settings on the load balancer.
[image]

Comment: Please add your load balancer/target group's health check settings. For example, it could be configured to do a health check every 60 seconds, and require 20 successful checks to consider a target healthy. Also check if the target group has [slow start mode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#slow-start-mode) enabled. Your application may just be taking a long time to start up. Seeing that the EC2 server is running just means the computer is "on", but the load balancer is still waiting on the software to start responding.

Comment: The load balancer is a Classic Load Balancer by the way.

Comment: is there a specific need to use CLB?

Comment: It really looks like the software you are running is taking 20 minutes to start up, before it begins responding successfully to the health checks. You should probably look at the server logs to investigate further.

Comment: @JatinMehrotra no there isn't a specific need. Perhaps an ALB 'Active Load Balancer' might be better.

Comment: I would suggest to do the following, change your load balancer to ALB and check for the issue, otherwise as @MarkB said, check your application warm-up time first, if that's the case, create an AMI  which has all the packages and dependencies bundled up, if that doest solve application time, try changing instances specs.

Comment: @DanielHollinrake ALB stands for "Application Load Balancer"